# Image doesn't fill its parent

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to load image as `decoration` for parent container but had the same result. I also couldn't find a way to load `svg` to `decoration`, so I stopped at `Stack`.

Here is my code:

```
class MainPageViewItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final mainPageViewItem;

  MainPageViewItem(this.mainPageViewItem);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      height: 150,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column (
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'some text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                      letterSpacing: 0.0015
                  ),
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 30, 12, 0),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  'some text',
                  style: MyTextStyles.bodyLightTextStyle,
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 20, 12, 15),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/vectors/wave_mask.svg',
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color> [
                mainPageViewItem.startColor,
                mainPageViewItem.endColor
              ],
              begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              end: Alignment.topRight,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0))
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is result:

[image]

**UPDATE:** `xml` code of "wave mask" `svg`:

```
<svg width="328" height="152" viewBox="0 0 328 152" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="16" y="12" width="296" height="120">
<rect x="16" y="12" width="296" height="120" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0)">
<path style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.25" d="M382.842 52.5C345.722 18.362 283.573 16.5 204.531 33.472C125.488 50.4441 105.488 -10.8214 71.9514 -82C38.6146 -152.757 179.945 -77.9483 179.945 -77.9483L272.883 -96.484L382.842 52.5Z" fill="url(#paint1_linear)"/>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.3">
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M-157.854 115.272C-44.2231 46.1702 64.6931 171.165 149.576 173.141C271.902 176.011 297.826 54.1459 360.305 106.524C422.784 158.902 481.373 204.464 533.973 116.2C586.572 27.936 639.405 72.3972 639.405 72.3972" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.405 73.9629C638.689 74.2268 584.552 28.7079 531.802 115.603C479.052 202.498 421.786 160.141 359.228 108.477C296.548 56.8012 270.301 173.948 147.388 171.301C62.2399 169.455 -45.3477 49.4305 -157.507 118.01" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.399 75.5286C637.967 76.0456 582.48 29.447 529.611 114.985C476.743 200.522 420.795 161.353 358.144 110.431C295.263 59.4674 268.7 171.902 145.193 169.461C59.7542 167.745 -46.4728 52.6962 -157.155 120.749" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.4 77.0943C637.251 77.8861 580.415 30.1861 527.421 114.366C474.427 198.546 419.803 162.619 357.067 112.406C293.985 62.1013 267.105 169.86 143.004 167.621C57.3202 166.036 -47.5976 55.9619 -156.808 123.487" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.401 78.6657C636.535 79.6998 578.344 30.92 525.251 113.748C472.157 196.575 418.831 163.842 356.009 114.338C292.706 64.7731 265.504 167.814 140.784 165.775C54.8412 164.326 -48.7803 59.227 -156.488 126.225" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.401 80.2316C635.819 81.5458 576.279 31.6592 523.041 113.134C469.803 194.609 417.937 164.991 354.913 116.265C291.539 67.2957 263.903 165.74 138.621 163.909C52.4072 162.59 -49.8472 62.4668 -156.115 128.916" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.402 81.7974C635.104 83.3486 574.214 32.4146 520.851 112.516C467.488 192.617 416.965 166.21 353.829 118.245C290.28 69.9623 262.301 163.715 136.426 162.095C49.947 160.908 -50.9725 65.7595 -155.769 131.703" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.402 83.3631C634.381 85.205 572.143 33.132 518.661 111.897C465.179 190.662 415.987 167.427 352.752 120.225C289.04 72.5967 260.706 161.696 134.238 160.25C47.5065 159.199 -52.0972 69.0198 -155.423 134.441" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.403 84.9235C633.666 87.0293 570.078 33.8657 516.471 111.273C462.864 188.68 415.015 168.645 351.675 122.136C287.724 75.2301 259.086 159.632 132.05 158.41C45.0341 157.489 -53.2221 72.2909 -155.076 137.18" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.403 86.4949C632.95 88.8647 568.006 34.605 514.281 110.66C460.555 186.715 414.036 169.863 350.598 124.106C286.497 77.8704 257.504 157.586 129.855 156.548C42.5745 155.758 -54.3466 75.53 -154.73 139.897" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.404 88.066C632.234 90.6943 565.941 35.3334 512.084 110.046C458.226 184.759 413.045 171.086 349.514 126.059C285.232 80.5045 255.922 155.54 127.666 154.73C40.1208 154.07 -55.4719 78.8172 -154.377 142.657" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.404 89.6319C631.518 92.5241 563.876 36.078 509.894 109.428C455.911 182.778 412.118 172.305 348.437 128.013C283.966 83.1442 254.321 153.499 125.472 152.884C37.6608 152.361 -56.5969 82.0831 -154.031 145.396" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.399 91.1975C630.796 94.3536 561.805 36.817 507.716 108.82C453.628 180.823 411.12 173.538 347.373 129.977C282.708 85.789 252.72 151.463 123.296 151.055C35.2139 150.662 -57.7089 85.3596 -153.672 148.145" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.399 92.7634C630.08 96.1834 559.74 37.5508 505.514 108.191C451.287 178.83 410.129 174.745 346.277 131.92C281.43 88.4177 251.112 149.405 121.063 149.204C32.722 148.941 -58.8723 88.6087 -153.364 150.872" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.4 94.3292C629.364 98.0131 557.669 38.2899 503.323 107.572C448.978 176.854 409.144 175.969 345.199 133.879C280.171 91.0627 249.511 147.369 118.9 147.364C30.2878 147.238 -59.9716 91.8803 -152.972 153.601" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.4 95.9002C628.623 99.8316 555.604 39.0342 501.133 106.959C446.663 174.883 408.166 177.192 344.122 135.827C278.893 93.6965 247.91 145.317 116.705 145.518C27.828 145.523 -61.0964 95.1405 -152.652 156.349" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.401 97.4662C627.958 101.678 553.52 39.7626 498.943 106.34C444.367 172.918 407.181 178.41 343.071 137.781C277.647 96.3311 246.341 143.271 114.543 143.679C25.4006 143.808 -62.1955 98.4068 -152.299 159.088" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.401 99.0319C627.217 103.508 551.467 40.4964 496.753 105.721C442.038 170.946 406.196 179.633 341.961 139.75C276.35 98.9701 244.713 141.24 112.328 141.855C22.9146 142.114 -63.3466 101.688 -151.953 161.843" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.402 100.598C626.494 105.337 549.402 41.2355 494.563 105.103C439.723 168.97 405.211 180.856 340.904 141.688C275.097 101.615 243.132 139.178 110.153 139.993C20.4743 140.389 -64.4519 104.938 -151.587 164.565" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.403 102.142C625.779 107.145 547.331 41.9478 492.367 104.463C437.402 166.977 404.226 182.095 339.808 143.641C273.806 104.254 241.511 137.136 107.913 138.153C17.9503 138.679 -65.6281 108.198 -151.285 167.303" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.403 103.729C625.063 108.997 545.266 42.7084 490.176 103.871C435.086 165.033 403.242 183.307 338.724 145.594C272.528 106.894 239.897 135.089 105.751 136.313C15.5419 136.97 -66.7209 111.464 -150.907 170.042" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.397 105.301C624.347 110.826 543.201 43.4477 487.986 103.252C432.771 163.057 402.25 184.53 337.621 147.548C271.25 109.539 238.29 133.048 103.537 134.467C13.0565 135.26 -67.8714 114.735 -150.586 172.78" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.398 106.866C623.631 112.672 541.129 44.2028 485.796 102.634C430.462 161.064 401.272 185.754 336.57 149.502C269.978 112.178 236.714 131.002 101.342 132.627C10.6028 133.551 -68.9966 117.995 -150.24 175.519" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.398 108.432C622.909 114.486 539.065 44.9204 483.606 102.015C428.147 159.109 400.274 186.982 335.493 151.455C268.7 114.823 235.119 128.955 99.1792 130.771C8.18161 131.842 -70.0829 121.261 -149.868 178.274" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.425 109.998C622.219 116.316 537.019 45.6545 481.461 101.402C425.902 157.15 399.283 188.21 334.409 153.409C267.423 117.451 233.518 126.914 96.9587 128.941C5.7028 130.127 -71.2524 124.521 -149.553 180.99" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.406 111.564C621.484 118.145 534.935 46.3935 479.232 100.783C423.529 155.173 398.298 189.455 333.364 155.363C266.176 120.113 231.949 124.868 94.8279 127.113C3.28115 128.434 -72.3135 127.799 -149.143 183.746" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.387 113.135C620.749 119.975 532.87 47.1273 477.022 100.164C421.175 153.201 397.3 190.667 332.255 157.31C264.86 122.757 230.322 122.821 92.6073 125.278C0.795598 126.729 -73.4705 131.069 -148.829 186.489" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.368 114.7C620.007 121.804 530.76 47.8657 474.813 99.5453C418.866 151.225 396.27 191.895 331.146 159.263C263.549 125.401 228.689 120.773 90.3802 123.448C-1.69652 125.03 -74.6278 134.345 -148.508 189.238" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.401 116.267C619.324 123.634 528.727 48.6054 472.655 98.9272C416.583 149.249 395.311 193.124 330.094 161.217C262.297 128.046 227.152 118.733 88.2245 121.576C-4.12374 123.294 -75.72 137.585 -148.129 191.95" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.402 117.832C618.608 125.464 526.656 49.339 470.458 98.3138C414.261 147.289 394.313 194.358 329.017 163.171C261.012 130.696 225.525 116.686 86.0103 119.736C-6.59681 121.606 -76.8644 140.85 -147.802 194.688" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.396 119.398C617.892 127.294 524.565 50.078 468.268 97.6954C411.971 145.313 393.315 195.602 327.94 165.125C259.728 133.346 223.923 114.634 83.8411 117.896C-9.02426 119.876 -77.97 144.117 -147.456 197.427" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.396 120.974C617.176 129.123 522.545 50.8122 466.091 97.0767C409.637 143.341 392.292 196.819 326.857 167.078C258.443 135.996 222.322 112.598 81.6464 116.056C-11.4968 118.166 -79.0948 147.377 -147.09 200.166" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.397 122.535C616.46 130.953 520.455 51.5511 463.888 96.458C407.322 141.365 391.32 198.048 325.799 169.032C257.159 138.646 220.728 110.53 79.4581 114.21C-13.9502 116.456 -80.2196 150.643 -146.743 202.904" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.398 124.101C615.738 132.783 518.39 52.2847 461.698 95.8393C405.006 139.394 390.335 199.293 324.702 170.985C255.874 141.296 219.126 108.505 77.2698 112.37C-16.4102 114.763 -81.3444 153.908 -146.397 205.643" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.398 125.667C615.022 134.607 516.318 53.0238 459.508 95.1991C402.698 137.374 389.324 200.499 323.645 172.912C254.596 143.919 217.545 106.437 75.0817 110.503C-18.8631 113.011 -82.4628 157.158 -146.044 208.354" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.399 127.232C614.306 136.442 514.253 53.7575 457.305 94.6071C400.356 135.457 388.32 201.77 322.516 174.892C253.298 146.607 215.924 104.417 72.8864 108.685C-21.3234 111.328 -83.5942 160.413 -145.692 211.12" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.399 128.798C613.584 138.277 512.182 54.4967 455.127 93.9888C398.073 133.481 387.322 203.004 321.465 176.846C252.007 149.262 214.329 102.365 70.6918 106.845C-23.7832 109.635 -84.7257 163.705 -145.351 213.853" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.4 130.37C612.875 140.107 510.117 55.236 452.937 93.3703C395.758 131.505 386.318 204.243 320.388 178.799C250.716 151.918 212.734 100.324 68.5034 105.005C-26.2429 107.92 -85.844 166.966 -145.005 216.597" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.4 131.935C612.159 141.937 508.052 55.9699 450.722 92.7514C393.391 129.533 385.319 205.493 319.304 180.753C249.425 154.573 211.126 98.2828 66.3085 103.165C-28.6962 106.194 -86.9691 170.232 -144.659 219.335" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.401 133.501C611.437 143.766 505.98 56.7088 448.55 92.1383C391.12 127.568 384.315 206.727 318.227 182.706C248.134 157.207 209.532 96.2361 64.1201 101.319C-31.1562 104.485 -88.0941 173.498 -144.313 222.074" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.395 135.067C610.727 145.596 503.916 57.4427 446.36 91.5197C388.805 125.597 383.285 207.971 317.15 184.66C246.842 159.878 207.93 94.2002 61.8996 99.4787C-33.6481 102.775 -89.2511 176.763 -143.998 224.812" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.396 136.633C610.005 147.448 501.845 58.155 444.17 90.9013C386.496 123.648 382.306 209.216 316.073 186.614C245.558 162.55 206.329 92.1484 59.7369 97.6392C-36.0438 101.077 -90.3182 180.03 -143.62 227.562" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.396 138.193C609.289 149.245 499.78 58.9046 441.98 90.2716C384.181 121.639 381.302 210.449 314.989 188.556C244.241 165.221 204.734 90.1015 57.5487 95.7989C-38.529 99.3563 -91.4685 183.289 -143.247 230.29" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.397 139.77C608.574 151.085 497.708 59.6707 439.79 89.6638C381.872 119.657 380.298 211.704 313.931 190.521C242.969 167.892 203.133 88.055 55.3539 93.9535C-40.9888 97.647 -92.5935 186.555 -142.927 233.028" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.397 141.335C607.851 152.915 495.643 60.3936 437.619 89.0508C379.596 117.708 379.293 212.938 312.835 192.474C241.678 170.548 201.532 86.0082 53.1592 92.1133C-43.4486 95.9374 -93.7248 189.821 -142.606 235.766" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.398 142.901C607.129 154.745 493.578 61.1275 435.41 88.432C377.242 115.736 378.289 214.204 311.758 194.428C240.38 173.235 199.937 83.9672 50.9706 90.2842C-45.9023 94.2443 -94.8303 193.071 -142.228 238.516" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.398 144.467C606.42 156.574 491.507 61.8665 433.22 87.8133C374.933 113.76 377.291 215.453 310.693 196.381C239.088 175.907 198.33 81.9204 48.7823 88.4279C-48.362 92.5186 -95.9683 196.353 -141.881 241.244" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.399 146.033C605.704 158.404 489.442 62.5841 431.029 87.1946C372.617 111.805 376.28 216.703 309.597 198.334C237.797 178.556 196.735 79.8737 46.5875 86.5877C-50.8154 90.8091 -97.0934 199.629 -141.535 243.982" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.4 147.604C604.988 160.234 487.377 63.3231 428.833 86.5758C370.289 109.828 375.275 217.958 308.52 200.288C236.499 181.249 195.134 77.8323 44.3992 84.7476C-53.2751 89.0995 -98.218 202.879 -141.188 246.72" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.394 149.17C604.266 162.063 485.305 64.073 426.643 85.9625C367.98 107.852 374.271 219.213 307.411 202.241C235.208 183.921 193.539 75.7858 42.1787 82.9071C-55.767 87.3896 -99.3686 206.144 -140.874 249.458" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.387 150.735C603.542 163.893 483.233 64.8122 424.458 85.3442C365.683 105.876 373.271 220.468 306.365 204.195C233.903 186.592 191.93 73.7392 40.0084 81.0621C-58.1959 85.6806 -100.475 209.41 -140.503 252.213" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.384 152.301C602.823 165.723 481.158 65.5457 422.252 84.7252C363.345 103.905 372.244 221.739 305.271 206.148C232.608 189.247 190.325 71.6978 37.8168 79.2219C-60.659 83.971 -101.604 212.676 -140.154 254.936" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.385 153.867C602.102 167.552 479.094 66.285 420.062 84.1067C361.03 101.928 371.24 222.984 304.208 208.102C231.317 191.935 188.731 69.6513 35.6224 77.3819C-63.1184 82.2616 -102.709 215.942 -139.832 257.674" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.387 155.411C601.393 169.382 477.03 66.997 417.873 83.4608C358.716 99.9247 370.237 224.244 303.112 210.055C230.046 194.606 187.131 67.6044 33.4351 75.5362C-65.5771 80.5411 -103.858 219.207 -139.459 260.413" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.388 157.025C600.665 171.233 474.959 67.7793 415.683 82.8963C356.408 98.0132 369.233 225.526 302.036 212.031C228.73 197.31 185.556 65.5799 31.2472 73.7179C-68.0236 78.8643 -104.97 222.489 -139.106 263.173" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.389 158.57C599.957 173.058 472.895 68.4971 413.481 82.2561C354.068 96.0151 368.229 226.765 300.96 213.941C227.44 199.949 183.937 63.4954 29.0538 71.8349C-70.4887 77.1333 -106.1 225.728 -138.765 265.89" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.391 160.136C599.242 174.871 470.844 69.231 411.305 81.6376C351.766 94.0441 367.232 228.031 299.877 215.916C226.142 202.653 182.336 61.4702 26.866 70.0163C-72.9413 75.4239 -107.224 228.999 -138.418 268.628" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.392 161.701C598.527 176.706 468.76 69.9695 409.09 81.0075C349.419 92.0454 366.196 229.296 298.8 217.869C224.858 205.335 180.735 59.4232 24.6716 68.1705C-75.4005 73.6979 -108.368 232.264 -138.071 271.367" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.386 163.273C597.811 178.536 466.696 70.7037 406.919 80.4003C347.143 90.0968 365.224 230.563 297.724 219.813C223.567 208.023 179.141 57.3825 22.4518 66.3304C-77.8919 71.9991 -109.505 235.503 -137.756 274.105" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.408 164.839C597.117 180.361 464.645 71.4432 404.75 79.7875C344.855 88.1318 364.24 231.829 296.648 221.777C222.245 210.71 177.542 55.336 20.3037 64.4911C-80.3051 70.2904 -110.583 238.797 -137.363 276.871" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.389 166.404C596.375 182.195 462.529 72.176 402.541 79.1684C342.552 86.1607 363.222 233.1 295.584 223.731C221.005 213.398 175.96 53.2894 18.1217 62.6455C-82.7521 68.5809 -111.702 242.073 -137.004 279.583" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.371 167.97C595.64 184.009 460.47 72.9152 400.331 78.5494C340.192 84.1835 362.218 234.372 294.488 225.684C219.694 216.091 174.339 51.2477 15.9076 60.805C-85.231 66.8549 -112.878 245.322 -136.677 282.321" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.392 169.536C594.945 185.855 458.426 73.6602 398.162 77.9312C337.898 82.2021 361.207 235.745 293.412 227.637C218.39 218.897 172.746 49.2013 13.721 58.9651C-87.6893 65.1616 -113.969 248.588 -136.328 285.06" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.393 171.102C594.217 187.684 456.356 74.3885 395.973 77.3125C335.59 80.2366 360.216 236.984 292.304 229.591C217.08 221.552 171.113 47.1542 11.5011 57.1246C-90.1422 63.463 -115.093 251.854 -135.981 287.798" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.393 172.673C593.513 189.514 454.29 75.1275 393.801 76.6995C333.312 78.2714 359.218 238.223 291.252 231.555C215.827 224.224 169.544 45.1186 9.35061 55.2904C-92.5897 61.7536 -116.206 255.131 -135.623 290.548" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
<g style="mix-blend-mode:overlay" opacity="0.5">
<path d="M639.396 174.244C592.794 191.317 452.208 75.8614 391.594 76.0809C330.98 76.3004 358.228 239.463 290.177 233.498C214.551 226.869 167.951 43.067 7.15161 53.4398C-95.092 60.0115 -117.342 258.386 -135.287 293.275" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
</g>
</g>
</g>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="312" y1="12" x2="229.097" y2="217.83" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="#1EDAE6"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="#00B5C0"/>
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient id="paint1_linear" x1="250.418" y1="8.26727" x2="176.583" y2="-34.6532" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop stop-color="white"/>
<stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

As you can see the "wave mask" doesn't fill entire space of container. Have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried setting the image as a decoration of the Container that is the parent of the Stack?

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes, as I said at the top of my post, I tried it and had the same result...

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu just tried it, nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap with this [Container](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html).

```
Container(
  width: double.maxFinite,
  height: double.maxFinite,
  child: SvgPicture.asset("/path"),
```

Comment: It didn't help with my "wave mask", but I also tried with other smaller vector file and it worked! Do you know what can be wrong with "wave mask" svg? I added this xml code to my question.

Comment: The problem is in svg file, are you using the recommended configuration for export?
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2842459/62599914-91de9c00-b8fe-11e9-8fb7-4af57d5100f7.png

Comment: Looks like I don't... How to open this window?

Comment: Adobe Illustrator > File > Export for Screen
You can find more information here:
https://theblog.adobe.com/adobe-illustrators-export-for-screens-saves-you-time-big-time/